# PCRE Regular Expression for to find href which contains domain in sublime?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have been trying to find a PCRE Regular Expression for to find all links which contains `www.aliexpress.com` as in :

```
 <a href="http://www.aliexpress.com/af/category/200118006.html?spm=2114.030010108.0.774.bcoKC8&amp;isAffiliate=y&amp;g=y">Parkas</a>
```

I want to just get whole href selected or the link under double quotes to replace that with  `#` But I want to make it work with sublime so any way to do that will be glad to know!

I tried but I was only able to search the whole `<a href="" > </a>` as in :

```
<\s*a[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>
```

Comment: Try [`(?<=\bhref=")([^"]*www.aliexpress.com[^"]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/1).

Comment: @stribizhev It works but one another problem..Some of my links are like this `href=     "www.aliexpress.com"` So the regex isn't recognizing them..! Like there is space between `href=     "link"`

Comment: FYI, Sublime Text uses Boost, not PCRE.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ahh...My bad..thanks for clearing that up..!

Comment: @MattDMo That `\s*` didn't really work..! Can you confirm that please?

Comment: @UmarShah: Use [`\bhref=\s*"\K[^"]*www\.aliexpress\.com[^"]*`](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/7) to match all links with `www.aliexpress.com`. With `category`: [`\bhref=\s*"\K[^"]*www.aliexpress.com(?:/category\b)?[^"]*`](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/8).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: [*Sublime Text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) engine from the Boost library.*](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)

Comment: @stribizhev this is a *very misleading* sentence. [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) != [Boost](http://www.boost.org/). If you're not convinced, try to use backtracking verbs like `(*SKIP)` with the Boost regex engine. PCRE is closer to Perl than Boost is, even though both try to be compatible. And yes, I know that's irrelevant for most sane people :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: It is true that when I just tried to  search for `"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,`  I got a notification that the expression is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [*Sublime Text uses the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) engine from the Boost library*](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) you may use the `\K` operator to omit all matched text by the pattern so far to "emulate" variable-width lookbehind.

To match all `href` links with `www.aliexpress.com`, use

```
\bhref=\s*"\K[^"]*www\.aliexpress\.com[^"]*
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/7).

Previous type links with an optional `/category` substrings after `www.aliexpress.com` can be matched with

```
\bhref=\s*"\K[^"]*www\.aliexpress\.com(?:/category\b)?[^"]*
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/9).

[image]

The regex breakdown:

- `\bhref=\s*"\K` - match a whole word `href` followed  by 0 or more whitespace symbols and a double quote and *omit* them all
- `[^"]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `"`
- `www\.aliexpress\.com` - match `www.aliexpress.com` literally
- `(?:/category\b)?` - match a `/category` substring or nothing (as `?` means *match 1 or 0 occurrences*)
- `[^"]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `"`

Comment: If you need more clarifications, please do not hesitate to drop a comment here.

Comment: Thanks you cleared everything..I can't ask more...But I will If I need anything..! Anyway I can get in contact with you..?

Comment: Ask SO regex questions -  I am often online.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(?<=\bhref=)\s*"([^"]*www.aliexpress.com[^"]*)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV4nW7/5)

Comment: It only matches with the ones who only have one character space not matches with the ones who have more than once spaces..!

Comment: Well..it really captures the starting quotes but spares the ending quotes..! :D

Comment: Besides can you update your answer with an another example also if I want to check for a directory like as `http://www.aliexpress.com/category/` like all links which contains slash category slash

Comment: @UmarShah for some reason it's working fine on the website, but not in Sublime, even if I add a non-capturing group for the spaces...

Comment: Great..Job..That will work guess I have to replace all those links with `"#` then to add the starting quotes back again..Can you also update your answer regarding my another request above?